# How to find if input has 0s at the beginning in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to detect if input has 0 at the beginning and erase them. I came up the following code. But this detect 0 anywhere in input. How can I change this to detect 0s at the beginning?

```
if input.include?("0") 
    @input = input.gsub(/^0+/,"")  
end
```

Comment: `if input =~ /^0+/ ...`

Comment: input.include?("0") verifies if the string has ANY 0 character...

Comment: FWIW, I don't see the point of the `if`. The gsub is already checking for leading zeroes.

Comment: `@input = input.gsub(/^0+/,"")` will delete all leading zeroes (if any) at the beginning of each line of your file and put what's left in the instance variable `@input`. (I presume you intend to have both a local variable `input` and instance variable `@input`.)  If you only want the substitution done in the first line of the file, use the anchor `\A` rather than `^` (and you can use `gsub` or `sub`): `@input = input.sub(/\A0+/,"")`. Note if you were to use the in-place version of `gsub`, `input.gsub!(/^0+/,"")`, that would return `nil` if no substitution were made (leaving `input` unchanged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is simplier to:

```
...my_string.start_with? "0"...
```

if it is not a string, simply cast it before (to_s). But there are other methods like:

```
...my_string.match(/\A0/)...
```

Or:

```
...if (my_string[0] == "0") ....
```

In cases that your string is multiline, all these method wil match the first character of the String. If you want to match any 0 on start of any line

```
...my_string.match(/^0/)...
```

Comment: `my_string.match(/^0/)` fails for multi-line strings. `/\A0/` should be preferred.

Comment: @undur_gongor String.starts_with? is there at least from [Ruby 1.9.3] (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F) and future.

Comment: @undur_gongor about /^0/ and /\A0/, /^0/ will not fail, but it considers as start (^) every new line start. /\A0/ will strictly match the first character of the string, no matter if it is multiline. So it depends on what specifically is wanted (as was not mentioned). +1 for the /\A0/ ;)

Comment: Sorry the correct is String.start_with?, without the final "s" on "starts"